# Why does query fail in separate `it` blocks of tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a React SignUp component. I'm writing tests with Jest as a runner and testing-library to write tests.

The signup component code( Using  materialize for styling) is :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { create } from "./api-user.js";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  card: {
    maxWidth: 600,
    margin: "auto",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(5),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  error: {
    verticalAlign: "middle",
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
    color: theme.palette.openTitle,
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 300,
  },
  submit: {
    margin: "auto",
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

export default function Signup() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    password: "",
    email: "",
    open: false,
    error: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const clickSubmit = () => {
    const user = {
      name: values.name || undefined,
      email: values.email || undefined,
      password: values.password || undefined,
    };
    create(user).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        setValues({ ...values, error: data.error });
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, error: "", open: true });
      }
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Sign Up
          </Typography>
          <TextField
            role="name"
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange("name")}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            role="email"
            id="email"
            type="email"
            label="Email"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            role="password"
            id="password"
            type="password"
            label="Password"
            className={classes.textField}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange("password")}
            margin="normal"
          />
          <br />{" "}
          {values.error && (
            <Typography component="p" color="error">
              <Icon color="error" className={classes.error}>
                error
              </Icon>
              {values.error}
            </Typography>
          )}
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={clickSubmit}
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
      <Dialog open={values.open} disableBackdropClick={true}>
        <DialogTitle>New Account</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            New account successfully created.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Link to="/signin">
            <Button color="primary" autoFocus="autoFocus" variant="contained">
              Sign In
            </Button>
          </Link>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to render the component and then verifying that the form has `Name`, `Email`, and  `Password` inputs.  The test file looks like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { screen, render, cleanup, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import SignUp from "./Signup";

describe("App component", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    render(<SignUp />);
  });
  it("should have the input field for name", () => {
    const nameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Name");
    expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should have the input field for email", () => {
    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email");
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should have the input field for password", () => {
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText("Password");
    expect(passwordInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  afterAll(cleanup);
});
```

The Problem: The first case/test always passes irrespective of what order I test the inputs. The `.getByLabelText` query is able to find the component for the first `it` block and fails for the next 2.

The message for running  the  test for  the  file above  is :

```
 FAIL  client/user/SignUp.test.js
  App component
    ✓ should have the input field for name (13 ms)
    ✕ should have the input field for email (3 ms)
    ✕ should have the input field for password (1 ms)

  ● App component › should have the input field for email

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: Email

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body />

      12 |   });
      13 |   it("should have the input field for email", () => {
    > 14 |     const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email");
         |                               ^
      15 |     expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
      16 |   });
      17 |   it("should have the input field for password", () => {

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
      at getAllByLabelText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/label-text.js:116:38)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19
      at Object.getByLabelText (client/user/SignUp.test.js:14:31)

  ● App component › should have the input field for password
```

and when I switch the order to :

```
 it("should have the input field for email", () => {
    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email");
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should have the input field for name", () => {
    const nameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Name");
    expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should have the input field for password", () => {
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText("Password");
    expect(passwordInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

The message changes to:

```
FAIL  client/user/SignUp.test.js
  App component
    ✓ should have the input field for email (19 ms)
    ✕ should have the input field for name (8 ms)
    ✕ should have the input field for password (6 ms)

  ● App component › should have the input field for name

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: Name

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body />

      13 |   });
      14 |   it("should have the input field for name", () => {
    > 15 |     const nameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Name");
         |                              ^
      16 |     expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
      17 |   });
      18 |   it("should have the input field for password", () => {

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
      at getAllByLabelText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/label-text.js:116:38)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19
      at Object.getByLabelText (client/user/SignUp.test.js:15:30)

  ● App component › should have the input field for password

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: Password

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body />

      17 |   });
      18 |   it("should have the input field for password", () => {
    > 19 |     const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText("Password");
         |                                  ^
      20 |     expect(passwordInput).toBeInTheDocument();
      21 |   });
      22 |   afterAll(cleanup);

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:40:19)
      at getAllByLabelText (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/queries/label-text.js:116:38)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:62:17
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:111:19
      at Object.getByLabelText (client/user/SignUp.test.js:19:34)
```

As you can see now the  query for `email` works versus the  other 2(`name` and `email`)

What's funnier, is that when I use all 3 queries inside a single `it` block then all test passes:

```
it("should have the input field for name", () => {
    const nameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Name");
    expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email");
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText("Password");
    expect(passwordInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

and it validates all 3 queries, you can test(SodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-material-ui-select-forked-5rixw3?file=/src/App.test.js:254-891) it by changing the parameter to the queries, it will fail if you changing it to like `const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email-failing");`

Can someone tell me, why the test library works in the same block and not in separate blocks? and how can I test three inputs? I have also tried different query methods e.g `.getByRole`  for the role attribute and it behaves in the same fashion i.e works in a single block and  2nd and 3rd blocks/tests fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering your component before all the tests. You should instead render component in each test. Don't use render in beforeAll block, use it inside each 'it' block.

```
import React from "react";
import { screen, render, cleanup, fireEvent } from "@testing- 
library/react";
import SignUp from "./Signup";

describe("App component", () => {
  it("should have the input field for name", () => {
    render(<SignUp />);
    const nameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Name");
    expect(nameInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should have the input field for email", () => {
    render(<SignUp />);
    const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText("Email");
    expect(emailInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("should have the input field for password", () => {
    render(<SignUp />);
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText("Password");
    expect(passwordInput).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  afterAll(cleanup);
});
```